# 2008 Ford Focus replacement passenger mirror

Tags: ford, focus

I'm trying to find a replacement passenger side mirror for a 2008 Ford Focus.  I don't need the full assembly, just the actual mirror part.  [Here is an image of the back of the mirror part](http://www.flickr.com/photos/51035766774@N01/9555123613/).  The part numbers on the back show I think a brand FoMoCo (Ford Motor Co?) with D161H and 18-690RH.

My Google and Amazon searches are turning up empty for the specific part numbers on the mirror, and I don't need the entire kit, just the mirror.  Is there a place on the Internet where you find specific OEM pieces or am I stuck needing to get the whole mirror and replacing the whole thing...or prying the mirror off of that to snap back on?

Comment: Do you need just the glass mirror part or the glass and the plastic backing piece that the glass attaches to?

Comment: @mikes the piece I have looks like the mirror part is glued to a black plastic piece; does the mirror come completely separate? Basically there's the mirror assembly that attaches to the car, and my broken piece that snaps onto the little panel in the assembly that adjusts. The mirror is cracked, but it seems like it's a single piece that snaps onto the swivel panel of the assembly. I can take more pics if that would help?

Comment: Check with a local glass shop. We have one in my area that will cut a mirror for under $10. Since the original is affixed maybe you can stick the new one onto the  old.

Comment: USA, it's a manual non-heated mirror.  I've contacted RockAuto and some "Fit Parts" (or something?) where I found some hits...it looks like I'll end up getting a new mirror from ebay and pry the broken one off the backing plate.  I don't need the whole assembly but it would be nice to have it already attached to the backing plate.  But the plate itself isn't broken so I should be able to glue a new mirror onto the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out http://car-part.com/

It is the largest parts database I have come across.

Most are used parts but for this part, I would not think that is a problem....

Answer (score 1):

Try the parts counter at a Ford Dealer or [Ford Parts](http://www.fordparts.com/) or [Team Ford Parts](http://www.teamfordparts.com/) (if you are in the US).  A couple quick searches at the last two indicate the mirror glass is available by itself.  The parts counter and Ford Parts will be more expensive, but you won't pay shipping at the counter or via Ford Parts if you pick up at a dealer.  If you absolutely do not want to get the wrong part, go to the parts counter at a dealer.  Bribe them with hot doughnuts and you may even get a cash discount.